# salesforce bulk load giving Union error when we use V2

Tags: bulk-api-v2

When we use same data with V1 - loaded fine but with V2 it's giving Union error

> Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. string <> boolean at the 13th column of the second table

Comment: In which method (GET/ POST/PUT/PATCH)of BULK API  v2 are you seeing this error? Are you able to include more details on steps you are following to replicate this error? Thanks

Comment: Yes - this error replicated every time in POST, Bulkload V2 version 56

Comment: Can you include Minimum Viable Code to reproduce this error. With the minimal details from the question, it is difficult to troubleshoot the scenario.